# How to open a react project like an app or by clicking index.htm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I'm working on a React project where we need to open an offline demo app by clicking index.html or another direct link (the person using it has to double-click in something and it should open), without `npm start`. It's for an offline demo app that needs to open, simply by clicking something.

I've tried changing "homepage": "./",

adding

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
```

replacing BrowserRouter to HashRouter.

but nothing seems to work. Any idea or tips on how to approach this?

EDIT: I solved it by creating a .bat file, which does `npm start` by clicking it.

Comment: By "offline", are you referring to "offline" in the context of a PWA or "offline" in the context of a user manually downloading the index.htm and opening it themselves in their browser "offline"?

Comment: Hi my first thought was givin the user the projetc folders (he is part of the team but doesn't know how to use visual code o anything like that, he just need to open the project demo easy for presentations) and tell him to open it by index.html.

Comment: so you want  to give your project without node.js (npm start run node server), you can perhaps read this link: https://dev.to/luispa/lets-try-react-without-nodejs-3a7

Comment: thank you very much i will try that now!